# can i say that $x=y$ if both have the same terms?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If I got that,

$$x=\dfrac{y^3+1}{2}\textrm{ and }y=\dfrac{x^3+1}{2}$$

then can I say that $x=y$ ? it looks correct but I'm not sure why.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not true. If that condition you state holds, the only thing you can conclude is that $x$ and $y$ are roots of certain polynomial of degree $9$ (the one obtained by substituting $x$ in $y$ or viceversa).

Comment: That's an easy rookie mistake to make,but it's not true, To see why easily, just draw the graphs of the 2 functions and you'll see how different they are.

Comment: They are not equal, just think that they are inverse function (very few function are inverse of themselves).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can certainly say so (contrary to what others have answered), provided you're interested only in real solutions. Not in general, but in this particular case, I mean.

If this system had a solution $(a,b)$ with $a\ne b$, we would have
$$
2a=b^3+1,\quad 2b=a^3+1
$$
from which we get $2(a-b)=b^3-a^3=(b-a)(b^2+ab+a^2)$ and, since $a\ne b$,
$$
a^2+ab+b^2=-2
$$
that has no real solution, a contradiction.

So the intersections of these curves can also be computed as the solutions of
$$
\begin{cases}
2y=x^3+1\\
y=x
\end{cases}
$$
and the resolvent equation is $x^3-2x+1=0$, which factors as $(x-1)(x^2+x-1)=0$ giving
$$
x=1
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x=\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$

---

More generally, if we have equations $y=f(x)$ and $x=f(y)$, where $f$ is a polynomial, we can certainly write
$$
y-x=f(x)-f(y)
$$
and, since $f(x)-f(y)$, as a polynomial in two variables, is divisible by $x-y$, we have
$$
x=y \qquad\text{or}\qquad \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=-1
$$
where the fraction denotes the quotient polynomial.

This can be done unless the equation $y-x=f(x)-f(y)$ is trivial, that is, when $f(x)-f(y)=y-x$ as polynomials. This is exactly the case when $f(z)=k-z$, which is the one mentioned by Hagen von Eltzen.

Of course things are more complicated if non polynomial functions are involved.

Comment: Thanks for giving this answer (which was contrary to several incorrect answers).  I'm not sure I agree with your argument about polynomials, though -- for example, if $y=1-x^2$ and $x=1-y^2$, this doesn't imply that $x=y$, even though $f(x)-f(y)=y^2-x^2\ne y-x$.

Comment: @user84413 No: in this case $(f(x)-f(y))/(x-y)=-y-x$ and the equation $-y-x=-1$ is satisfied also for $x+y=1$. So in this case also the “or” branch must be followed, which doesn't happen with the problem in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I'm sorry for my misunderstanding; I didn't interpret what you were saying about polynomials correctly.

Answer (score 3):

[image]![you can solve a system of equation and find the solution(s) . or ,you can put x from 1st relation into 2nd relation ,to find roots then you have x,y .the picture may help you ][2]

or ,you can put x from 1st relation into 2nd relation ,to find roots then you have x,y .the picture may help you .try this

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. You have $x=f(y)$ ans $y=f(x)$ for some function $f$. If you had (simpler) $x=10-y$ and $y=10-x$ you could not say $x0y$ either. After all it *might* be that $x=3$ and $y=7$.

(At least $x$ (and $y$) are fixed points of the iterated function $x\mapsto f(f(x))$.)

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the expression gives:
$$
x=\frac{Y^3+1}{2} \Rightarrow \\
Y = \left\{
\begin{array}{rc} 
\sqrt[3]{2x-1} & \mbox{for } x \ge 1/2 \\
-\sqrt[3]{1-2x} & \mbox{for } x < 1/2
\end{array}
\right.
$$ 
Compare this with
$$
y=\frac{x^3+1}{2}
$$
which should be different in general.

[image: y(x), the two parts of Y(x) and the identity function]

The plot indicates three common points, which have to lie on the identity line.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Solve for $x$ and $y$ for both functions. When doing so, you'll get $y=\sqrt [3]{2x-1}$ which does not equal ${x^3 + 1}\over 2$. And $x=\sqrt [3] {2y-1}$ which does not equal ${y^3 + 1}\over 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say this, and this applies more generally to any increasing function:

If $f$ is an increasing function and $f(x)=y$ and $f(y)=x$, then $x=y$.

$\underline{Pf}$ Suppose instead that $x\ne y$, so WLOG we can assume that $x<y$.

$\;\;\;\;$Then $f(x)<f(y)\implies y<x$, which gives a contradiction; so $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the graphs cut along $ x=y $ with real roots/ intersections.